# (Java) How to create a JAR file in the command line when code contains UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, utf-8, jar

I have a program that uses certain characters (arrows, gender symbols) that are not typically supported. When compiling in Eclipse, I just choose "save as UTF-8" and it works fine. However, when I'm in the console trying to compile (using javac *.java or something to that effect) it throws an error because of those UTF-8 characters. How do I adjust the way I compile so it is able to use the UTF-8 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating `JAR` file is mainly like archiving the `.class` files so you should not get any error because of `UTF-8` characters in source files.

For resolving compilation error due to `UTF-8` characters, use `-encoding` argument for specifying source files encoding -

```
javac SourceJavaFile.java -encoding UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JAR file using eclipse natively by right-clicking on your project and then selecting Export. From there you can expand the Java node and select the JAR File type, and configure it from there. Reference [here](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm) from the eclipse website for a full instruction of using the built-in JAR File maker on eclipse. I hope this allows for the use of UTF-8 exclusive characters which you are using.